# How to parse inline xsd with msdata:IsDataSet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

I've been trying to parse an xml API response into a js object. Easy enough, but I want to use the (verbose) `msdata:Caption` from an inline schema to substitute the unhelpful element name:

```
<DataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" >
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:element name="DataSource" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element name="Values">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:choice>
                                <xsd:element name="XA1" msdata:Caption="Variable Name" type="xsd:string" />
....
```

There's documentation about how to do parse such data in .net (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can't find a JS implementation. Has anyone come across a project to solve this?

Comment: maybe share what you have done so far ? thanks.

Comment: and, do you mean that you are trying to parse the xml into a json object ? js object is a vague description. let us know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: nothing mate, just seeing what's out there and if I can avoid writing a custom parser. would have thought .net `DataSet`s aren't too uncommon  ...